# How can I back up files from multiple accounts?

Tags: ubuntu-one, multiple-users

How do I use Ubuntu One to backup files belonging to three different user accounts on my laptop - mine, my wife's and our business files, each of which has its own login account and therefore own copies of Documents, etc.

When I try to backup (say) my business files, my own *personal* Ubuntu One account is the default and there is a conflict of folder names.
It happens similarly with my wife's files.

Is it just a matter of registering two more Ubuntu One login account?

Answer (score 1):

You should use more accounts, yes. It's not a good practice to share accounts in any case. It's better to share documents and folders between the users. I'm not sure what happens if you share the folder both on Ubuntu One and locally. I don't think it should cause any problems, but you may have to download files even though they're already on disk. You should probably share a test folder first to see how that works.

Remember that Ubuntu One is also used to login to other websites, so it is a very good idea for everyone to have their own accounts.